# Find NRIC from a large text file and replace NRIC first 4 characters with X

Tags: powershell

I have requirement to find NRIC field from text file and mask first 4 characters using PowerShell. So far below is my code.

```
$FileName = "E:\test.txt"
$patternNRIC = '[SGTGsftg]\d{7}\w'

$file= New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg $FileName
while($s= $file.ReadLine())
{
    $s = $s -replace $patternNRIC ,'XXXX'
    Write-Host $s -BackgroundColor Magenta
}
$file.Close()
```

Problem with above is it replaces whole NRIC with XXX character which I don't want. I want to replace only first 4 characters while keeping rest intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the [National Registration Identity Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Registration_Identity_Card) definition, hiding just the first 4 characters of the **NRIC** doesn't guaranty much privacy of the card owner (there are probably far less than 100 persons that meat the disclosed part and if you know the birthday and the fact that the first following digit is likely a `0`, it is probably down to a single person that matches the information!).
Excerpt from WikiPedia:

> ***only the last three or four digits and the letters** are publicly displayed or published as the first three digits can easily give away a person's age.*

Anyways:

- PowerShell is case insensitive (so there is no need to list lowercase *and* uppercase characters)
- To check for and following characters (and not replacing them) use the [lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- I recommend you to also use word boundaries (`\b`) to make sure that the NRIC is of a given length and not a part of another sequence

```
$Test = 'I have requirement to find NRIC field, like S1234567G, and mask the first 4 characters.'
$Pattern = '\b[STFG]\d{3}(?=\d{4}\w\b)'
$Test -Replace $Pattern, 'XXXX'
```

Result

```
I have requirement to find NRIC field, like XXXX4567G, and mask the first 4 characters.
```

Comment: You are right. We changed the algorithm alreday and now want to display only last  4 characters . What will be pattern in that case?

Comment: Read now about assertion. Though still not sure how exactly it works, below pattern works for me: '\b[STFG]\d{4}(?=\d{3}\w\b)'